# Is it compulsory to register our web application on Google Apps before implementing OAuth?

Tags: java, oauth

I am developing a Java application that needs to access personal account Google Data of a user. The development is currently in netbeans on my localhost. I am implementing 3-legged OAuth. And while sending Grant request, it sends me Unauthorized Request Token and then redirects to Callback URL.

While trying to access Access Token, it gives me Error "Error Getting HTTP Response". Now, as per it given in [Google Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#GetAuth), it is given that "If the application is not registered, Google uses the oauth_callback URL, if set; if it is not set, Google uses the string "anonymous"." Does it mean that I must register my application on Google Apps Engine before granting authorization & accessing request ? Please Help.

For reference : [OAuth for Web Applications](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html), [OAuth in the Google Data Protocol Client Libraries](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, it's probably not the registration piece that's causing you trouble.  It sounds like you just haven't implemented OAuth correctly — not that doing so is easy.  The OAuth process is roughly as follows:

1. Get a request token.  You must pass in a bunch of stuff that declares what kind of stuff you want access to and where you want Google to send the user when they're done granting you access to that data.  This is where you pass in your consumer key, which you get by registering.  The consumer key will be the string `anonymous` if you are developing an installed application (i.e., mobile app, desktop app, etc).  This is a work-around; the alternative would be to embed your client secret or RSA private key within the application itself, which is a very, very bad idea.  If you use 'anonymous', you should absolutely be setting the `xoauth_displayname` parameter.  (Actually, everyone should set this parameter, but it's especially important if you're using `anonymous`.)
2. Once you have a request token, you then redirect the user to the special authorization endpoint, passing along the request token key in the query string.  Assuming the user grants access, Google will redirect the user back to the callback URL that you associated with your request token.  The request token is now authorized, but it can't be used directly just yet.
3. Once the request token is authorized, you can exchange it for an access token key/secret pair.  The access token key/secret can then be used to sign requests for protected resources, such as the private data in the API you're trying to access.

For web applications, registering is almost always a good idea.  It makes it much easier for users to manage their access tokens and revoke them if your application misbehaves or if they don't want you to have access anymore.  If you don't register, your application will probably show up as a fairly scary-looking 'anonymous' in that list.  It's really only installed applications that you wouldn't want to register for.  You probably also want to register for an [API key](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).  An API key will dramatically increase your rate limit and it will also allow Google to get in touch with you if your application starts to malfunction.

I'd link to the OAuth docs, but you've already found them.  Hope my explanation helps!

Comment: Definitely agree with "everyone should set this parameter". As it is optional, I did't paid any interest with it ! My Mistake ! And the conflict was there in between 1 & 2 only ! However, you clarified it !

Comment: Also, here are the docs on registering your domain.  http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html#new  Note this this registration process has nothing to do with App Engine — you could just as easily use some other webhost.  Though, as a Google employee, naturally, I recommend the use of GAE anyways.  :-D

Comment: I have registered my application on app-engine. I am also granting Access from my account. But, there is no entry under "My Account", even though it is returning the verifier. And when I try to fetch Access Token by running another servlet, is shows null/empty string !

Comment: Just have a look for more info : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836781/how-to-get-access-token-using-gdata-in-java

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing on your local machine, you'll continue to get the same result as above.

For more interesting tests, then yes, you'll have to register your app and push it to the app engine.

Answer (score 0):

Google will check if the domainname of the return-url is registered. You could also modify your dns/host-file to point the domain-name you're using to localhost.