# Unknown authorization header - Error 401

Tags: java, oauth, request-headers

I am accessing Google Spreadsheet feeds using HMAC-SH1 sign. My Code is :

```
GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
        oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
        oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
        oauthParameters.setScope("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/");
        oauthParameters.setOAuthType(OAuthParameters.OAuthType.THREE_LEGGED_OAUTH);
        oauthParameters.setOAuthToken(request.getSession().getAttribute("oauth_token").toString());
        oauthParameters.setOAuthTokenSecret(request.getSession().getAttribute("oauth_token_secret").toString());

GoogleService googleService = new GoogleService("wise", "searceapps-searcegadget2-1");
        googleService.setOAuthCredentials(oauthParameters, new OAuthHmacSha1Signer());
        URL feedUrl = new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full/");

        SpreadsheetFeed resultFeed = googleService.getFeed(feedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
```

But, I am getting the error :

> Oauth.requestServlet doGet: null
>   com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException:
>   OK   Unknown
>   authorization header
>
> ## Unknown
>   authorization header
>
> ### Error
>   401
>
> at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:600)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:631)
>     at
>   com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
>     at
>   Oauth.accessFeeds.access(accessFeeds.java:74)

What is the problem with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the server is sending a "401 Unauthorized" response with a [WWW-Authenticate](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.47) header that the client code doesn't recognize.  It may even be sending no WWW-Authenticate header at all ... *vide* the "null" in the exception message.

(The latter is a violation of the HTTP 1.1 specification.  A 401 response is *required* to have a WWW-Authenticate header that the client uses to decide *how* to authenticate.  Refer to the spec for details.)

---

So why might this be happening talking to a Google feed?  Perhaps you've configured your client with the wrong URL?  Perhaps your client is trying to connect via some poorly designed proxy?

Comment: As per it specified here : http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html, I have authorized client & also I am logged in.

Comment: Wrong URL again not possible as I have registered this application online on GAE ! Even the scope & Feed URL I am specifying is correct & working !

Comment: Well, I'm stumped.  Perhaps you should use wireshark or something like that to see what the HTTP request and response really contain.  The other thing you could do is plough through the Google search hits for this error.

Comment: Oh ! Surprising that from a complete new project, it works ! But, here the access token is in session from the start. While in this application I am fetching the Access Token from Google Datastore, which was stored previously !

Comment: That one more problem with Google Jump currently still unsolved is this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921523/userservice-getcurrentuser-returns-null

Answer (score 0):

See [Android Google Calendar Authorization Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670517/android-google-calendar-authorization-problem). Google is doing something different with the calendar feeds, redirecting with a new 'gsessionid' parameter in the querystring; may be the same problem with spreadsheet.