# Android Google Calendar Authorization Problem

Tags: android, oauth, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to make an app that accesses a user's Google Calendar using OAuth. I have the code in place that gets all of the proper tokens and they are saved into some preferences. I used the tutorial [here](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/10/oauth-flow-in-android-app/) to do this all, by the way. I have successfully changed the scope and request URL's so that I'm getting the needed tokens. The problem comes when I actually try to USE the token. Instead of calendar info, I get back some HTML that says "Unknown authorization header Error 401". The request URL I am using is:

```
 https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full
```

and the scope is:

```
 http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/
```

I have tried replacing 'default' with my email address (which is also the one that I  used for the OAuth) to no avail. Am I using the wrong URL? if not, what else could cause this error? I have been looking for a few days now to find someone who has accessed the Calendar using OAuth, but everything I have found is people giving up because it's too difficult or doesn't work.

EDIT:

I believe my header is correct, here is an example of it:

```
 OAuth oauth_token="************-********-**********-****", 
 oauth_consumer_key="anonymous", 
 oauth_version="1.0", 
 oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
 oauth_timestamp="1303161387", 
 oauth_nonce="*******************", 
 oauth_signature="*******************"
```

That is pulled directly from my app, and from what I could find it looks right to me, but I'm still getting the error above (Unknown Authorization Header Error 401).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Authorization header needs to be "Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="deadbeefdeadbeef" oauth_version="1.0" ....

See http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#RequestToken. You can, supposedly, also but the authorization parameters in the querystring or in the body of a POST, but I have not attempted that.

---

As noted in the comments below, Google is now, at least with the Calendar feed, appending a 'gsessionid=' querystring and redirecting; and so a redirect handler must create a new nonce and timestamp, and make a new signature making sure to add the gsessionid to the base signature string in the correct lexicographical order (preceding any of the oauth_ variables).

Comment: The header is already like that, yet somehow it's not liking it. I will add an example of my header to my question.

Comment: all the values in quotes are urlencoded using the special encoding of the oauth spec, correct? meaning, anything except [^0-9A-Za-z._~-] is %xx-coded.

Comment: and it's all on one line, right? not split across several lines as you showed it.

Comment: I guess you must, if you got all the way through getting the long-lived token, but I'm just throwing things out there. I know how annoying these laconic replies from the Google server can be; I finally made my first successful request yesterday. first I hadn't stripped the linefeeds from the strings when I pulled them from the file, and then I wasn't using the correct URL for the contacts list; getting a 400 Bad Request error for each mistake.

Comment: ...which prompted me, "hey! try his URL with your own script, dummy!" so I did. same error you're getting. so hang on, maybe we can sort this.

Comment: Yeah, it's all on one line, but I split it up for readability on here. I'm looking in to the error, and trying to find out what might cause it. As far as retrieving the contacts, the tutorial I used uses the scope https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ and URL https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json and it works just fine.

Comment: I think I found it using the OAuth Playground. Google sends a redirect header, with a new parameter 'gsessionid' attached to the URL. This has to be added to the signature base string, and the signature recalculated! I know I've got to fix my script to do this, you might also need to.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but...how exactly do I do that? Do I just append the 'gsessionid' onto the end of the header, and pass it back in?

Comment: No, we need to rebuild the base string from scratch, such as a new nonce and timestamp, and adding in the gsessionid in the right place: GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts&oauth_consumer_key%3Eexample.net... now becomes GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts&gsessionid=... because gsessionid precedes any of the oauth_ variables in lexicographical order. Then recalculate the signature based on that, and rebuild the Authorization header. I haven't yet accomplished it myself, so I'm not sure as to all the details.

Comment: Finally got mine working today, so I know it works now: put the gsessionid into the signature base string, make a new nonce and timestamp, sign the new string, and re-create the Authorization header with the new nonce, timestamp, and signature before continuing with the redirect. I fixed my Python script but not my Android app, but the mechanism should be basically the same.